# Discard a seconds from localtime in Perl

Tags: perl

ALL,

I have a following line in my script:

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime( $stop_epoch);
```

in order to generate Zulu time, which does not need seconds. And so when executing my script is printing a warning:

```
Name main::sec used only once: possible typo
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

TIA!!

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 5):

You should be using lexical variables wherever possible, for which this warning does not apply.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
```

The `undef` assignment trick is also allowed in a `my`.

```
my (undef,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
```

See [perlsub](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

If you had declared the variables instead of using global variables, you wouldn't have gotten this warning.

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
```

That said, you don't have to use a variable you don't need. You could use

```
my (undef,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
```

or

```
my ($year,$mon,$mday,$hour,$min) = ( localtime($stop_epoch) )[5,4,3,2,1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with `undef` on the left side of the assignment and Perl will not assign it.

```
(undef,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
```

The other way to get rid of warnings, of course, is to disable warnings. It's not necessarily a bad programming practive if you do this in a small scope and in a context where you are sure the warning is spurious and unhelpful.

```
{
    no warnings 'once';
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime($stop_epoch);
}
```